# Entity Framework 6 not saving changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5, savechanges

I've got an MVC5 web application that uses SQL Server 2008 as a back end database along with the Entity Framework 6. There's no error in adding code but data can not get stored in to database.

my model context.cs looks like

```
public partial class checkin_checkoutEntities2 : DbContext
    {
        public checkin_checkoutEntities2()
            : base("name=checkin_checkoutEntities2")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Advance_Booking> Advance_Bookings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<employee_reg> employee_reg { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Extend_Stay> Extend_Stay { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Guest_reg> Guest_reg { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RoomBooking> RoomBooking { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Rooms_ms> Rooms_ms { get; set; }
    }
```

and my adding method is as below

```
 ab.Room_id = Convert.ToInt32(ab_rm_no.room_id);
 ab.Guest_id = Convert.ToInt32(frm["guest_id"].ToString());
 ab.Expected_checkin  = Convert.ToDateTime(frm["BookedDateFR"].ToString());
 ab.Expected_checkout = Convert.ToDateTime(frm["BookedDateTO"].ToString());
 
 db.Advance_Bookings.Add(ab);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: did you try to to debug and see what's getting added in db.Advance_Bookings.Add(ab);?

Comment: Does your DataContext load entities from the database? Your connection string seems suspicious, to say the least.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Yes it loads entities form db.

Comment: @MalavSevak And your user can insert into the desired tables? Perhaps confirm that from Management Studio

Comment: @KushalR I want  to add entry into  database table . and there's no error for sure. i have tried debugging by putting breakpoints

Comment: i just comment this line  //using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope()) and it works now perfectly why this happened sorry for silly question

Comment: Did you call `transaction.Commit()` after saving? Otherwise, with an active transaction the save will be thrown away at the end of the transaction `using` block.

Comment: @grek40 i forgot to add commit thank you now its working .

Comment: the same issue I am facing, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments, the `db.SaveChanges();` was wrapped in a transaction

```
using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    // some changes and db.SaveChanges();
}
```

and it was working only without the transaction.

The reason is, that a transaction needs to be committed in order to persist the saved changes.

```
using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    // some changes and db.SaveChanges();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Otherwise the changes would be discarded at the end of the transaction block.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your code a bit and try following:
Rather using db.Advance_Bookings.Add(ab) can you use following:

```
db.Entry(ab).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Also, as far my understanding this problem can only occur if the DbContext is disconnected (as it's not giving any error).
You can try to wrap your code in a using block

```
using (var ab = new DbContext()) 
{
//instantiate the object and saveChanges.
}
```